# How to make the on click feature not last only while holding down the mouse?

Tags: html, css, click, hover

I am trying to get my search boxes to change a different colour on click but at the moment it only changes colour for the duration of time I am holding down on my mouse. As soon as I let go of pressing down the cursor it changes back. How do I make it so it changes colour but as soon as I click something else on the page (even whitespace) it changes back to the original colour?

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LPVfn/

Cheers!

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
.search:focus
```

instead of

```
.search:active
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a js library called HoverIntent.  Maybe you could use it to get the desired effect.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

I'm currently using it to delay displaying a div tooltip for a few milliseconds after the user hovers over the search box.